# Php algorithm - How to achieve that without eval

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a class that keeps data stores/access data by using words.separated.by.dots keys and it behaves like the following:

```
    $object = new MyArray()
    $object->setParam('user.name','marcelo');
    $object->setParam('user.email','some@email.com');

    $object->getParams();

    /*
    array(
        'user' => array(
            'name' => 'marcelo',
            'email' => 'some@email.com'
        )
    );
    */
```

It is working, but the method unsetParam() was horribly implemented. That happened because i didn't know how to achieve that without eval() function. Although it is working, I found that it was a really challenging algorithm and that you might find fun trying to achieve that without eval().

```
class MyArray {
   /**
     * @param string $key
     * @return Mura_Session_Abstract 
     */
    public function unsetParam($key)
    {
        $params = $this->getParams();
        $tmp = $params;
        $keys = explode('.', $key);

        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            if (!isset($tmp[$key])) {
                return $this;
            }
            $tmp = $tmp[$key];
        }

        // bad code!
        $eval = "unset(\$params['" . implode("']['", $keys) . "']);";
        eval($eval);

        $this->setParams($params);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The test method:

```
public function testCanUnsetNestedParam()
{
    $params = array(
        '1' => array(
            '1' => array(
                '1' => array(
                    '1' => 'one',
                    '2' => 'two',
                    '3' => 'three',
                ),
                '2' => array(
                    '1' => 'one',
                    '2' => 'two',
                    '3' => 'three',
                ),
            )
        ),
        '2' => 'something'
    );

    $session = $this->newSession();
    $session->setParams($params);

    unset($params['1']['1']['1']);
    $session->unsetParam('1.1.1');

    $this->assertEquals($params, $session->getParams());
    $this->assertEquals($params['1']['1']['2'], $session->getParam('1.1.2'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this it?

```
<?php
$params = array(
    '1' => array(
        '1' => array(
        '1' => array(
            '1' => 'one',
            '2' => 'two',
            '3' => 'three',
        ),
        '2' => array(
            '1' => 'one',
            '2' => 'two',
            '3' => 'three',
        ),
        )
    ),
    '2' => 'something'
    );

function unsetParam( &$array, $paramString ) {
$cur =& $array;
$splitted = explode( ".", $paramString );
$len = count( $splitted ) - 1;

    for( $i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i ) {

        if( isset( $cur[ $splitted[ $i ] ] ) ) {
        $cur =& $cur[ $splitted[ $i ] ];
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }


    }

unset( $cur[ $splitted[$i] ] );


}

unsetParam( $params, "1.1.1");

print_r( $params );

/*
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
            (
                [1] => one
                [2] => two
                [3] => three
            )

        )

    )

    [2] => something
)
*/
```

Comment: creative use of references :)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could make your code easier if you only split to a multidimension array in your `getParams` method:

```
class MyArray {
   private $params = array();

   public function setParam($key, $value) {
       $this->params[$key] = $value;
   }
   /**
     * @param string $key
     * @return Mura_Session_Abstract 
     */
    public function unsetParam($key)
    {
        unset($this->params[$key]);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getParams() {
        $retval = array();
        foreach ($this->params as $key => $value) {
            $aux = &$retval;
            foreach (explode(".", $key) as $subkey) {
                if (!isset($aux[$subkey])) $aux[$subkey] = array();
                $aux = &$aux[$subkey];
            }
            $aux = $value;
        }
        return $retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, imho; the keys are unique so why is a multi-dimensional array even useful? Just store/retrieve using the string.with.dots unless there is some compelling detail we haven't heard yet?

Comment: Multi-dimensional array fits better to my needs. My class was a lot like the above and I ended up changing.

Comment: @Kato, let's bring your argument to its logical conclusion: why is this whole class even needed? :D

Comment: @Kato that's my point. He was worry about internally behavior when it does not matter. Only `getParams` would make some difference in return value...

Comment: @Esailija It's seems to be a configuration class. To me, he wants to do something like a Registry Pattern...

Answer (score 0):

@gustavotkg and @Esailija have both offered some great ideas. Here is another simple, easy to understand, and short approach that avoids unset() altogether (which can get [quirky](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20problems%20with%20unset) in some cases).

This would, of course, be most useful when $params is limited to less than, say, 1k-10k of values (which starts to get a bit pricey in the CPU/memory dept):

```
<?php

$params = array(
   '1' => array(
      '1' => array(
         '1' => array(
            '1' => 'one-one',
            '2' => 'one-two',
            '3' => 'one-three',
         ),
         '2' => array(
            '1' => 'two-one',
            '2' => 'two-two',
            '3' => 'two-three',
         ),
      )
   ),
   '2' => 'something'
);

function filterParams($params, $refKey, $base = '') {
   $newvals = array();
   foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
      $joinedKey = $base? $base . '.' . $k : $k;
      if( $joinedKey != $refKey ) {
         $newvals[$k] = is_array($v)? filterParams($v, $refKey, $joinedKey) : $v;
      }
   }
   return $newvals;
}

var_dump(filterParams($params, '1.1.2'));
```